# Merge two nginx servers

Tags: http, nginx, https, webserver, nginx-config

This nginx config is supposed to redirect

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

to `https://example.com`

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  root {:siteRoot};  
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
  index index.html;
}

server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

It works fine, but can it be merged somehow to avoid all the duplicate code ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you will need to use ifs and "if is evil" https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/   in nginx. You could set a single server bracket with both domains and separate with ifs the scheme and then the domain to handle them separately in the same "server" bracket. Personally I would let it stay like that. The variables $host and $scheme can be used to compare in the ifs. If you need any help with that say it, I just wanted to clarify that. (in the last part of that link it explains how to use the "ifs" correctly if you still want to use them).Hope I helped

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  root {:siteRoot};  
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen 80;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  if ($scheme = http) {
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }

  if ($host = 'www.example.com') {
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }
    index index.html;

}
```

As I commented, I like to separate in servers my different options in nginx, as I think of it not as "code". But I think what What I just wrote should work for you if you want to have it all in the same server. I'm setting up a virtual server to check if the "ifs" written work as intended, as the concept is right, but I need to check the code in depth.

Comment: But in the page you linked it says ifs are bad if they are used inside the location block. Here they are used outside, so I guess it's ok? My thinking was that having 3 server blocks for each website would result in slower performance than having a single server block

Comment: It all comes to: if you don't ever use ifs on nginx, you won't get used to it. This is a "best advices", not an absolute ( thats why I gave you an answer on what I think is a correct code for your problem). If it goes faster, fantastic, and I hope I helped, happy new year :)